# Accessing Ubuntu via external IP address on the same network causes entire network to crash, and other issues concerning the topic

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns, lan

**Full diagnostic:** When I am connected to the same network as my Ubuntu server (on my home network), and I try to access my server, either via the browser, FTP, SSH, ... via its external IP (and domain name), my network crashes. I get disconnected from the Internet on all my devices at home, and the only sites I am able to visit are Google sites (such as google.com, youtube.com), and a few other sites.
I fix this by turning off and on the modem as well as the server (for good measure), but the moment I access my server by its external IP, the issue reoccurs. Note by the way that accessing my server by its internal IP address while on the same network works fine, and accessing it via its external IP address on another network works fine too, or at least in the most cases. It happens too that although the network my server runs on works fine, any device outside its network can no longer connect to it (but the server itself can still connect to outside networks). As a final note I noticed that if I do a quick connect to my server via its external IP (e.g. I would quickly browse to my main web page), it doesn't cause any trouble, but if I would make use of the server for a longer period of time (e.g. upload a large amount of files via FTP), then it does start acting up.

**When it began:** A few months ago, my ISP installed a new modem, as my old one broke. The first few weeks were fine, then I did something stupid: a friend of mine told me Libreoffice was installed by default on Ubuntu server versions (?), so I ran `sudo apt-get purge libre*`, which messed with my database (lol) as well as phpmyadmin, and a few other services I hosted via Apache2. I was able to reinstall everything and get everything back to work, but it was then when I ran into the issue. 
Today, I decided to completely reinstall my server. I wiped off **everything** from my hard drives and did a complete and fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04 (the same version as before). Everything *seemed* to work fine, until eventually the problem occurred again. It first occurred pretty early on when I noticed I could not connect to the server from an outside network, even though browsing to it by its external IP from the same network worked fine. I did the usual and reset my modem, and let it slide.
Then, when I had installed PhpMyAdmin, suddenly my network went flat. At this point, anytime I would connect to the server via its external IP, it crashes the network. I first thought it might've been PhpMyAdmin, but uninstalling it was to no avail. Then I thought, maybe it could be the DNS (since some websites like Google still work but others don't), yet changing from Cloudflare (1.1.1.1) to Google's DNS (8.8.8.8) again did not help anything.

**What I do and don't know yet:** The problem doesn't (seem to) lie with my DNS, nor does it lie with any of the services on my server (Apache, PhpMyAdmin, MariaDB, etc.), reinstalling Ubuntu entirely was no success either.
I have not yet tried to host my server on another network besides that of my home, maybe it's the new modem I have that is somehow incompatible with my server, but that doesn't explain why in the first few weeks of owning the new modem there were no issues.

Please help me, this is annoying me and my family members greatly. I am open to sharing more information if it is thus necessary. I'll leave my Netplan configuration of my Ethernet port eno1 here:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.0.170/24
            gateway4: 192.168.0.1
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 8.8.8.8
                search:
                - 8.8.8.8
            optional: true
    version: 2
```

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: This seems to be a problem with your modem, and not with Ubuntu. If you try to reach any device in your local network through the router's external address, the router is supposed to simply drop the packets, i.e. the device is not accessible. The router should not crash. Have you tried searching the web with the make and model of the router and these symptoms?

Comment: @Jos I will look into that. Thank you for the heads up

Comment: It seems like the network outage only affects IPv4 sites, and not IPv6 websites, this seems to me like you installed an IPv4 DHCP server on your machine